# Open a File Browser?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am making a 3D renderer using Win32 and GDI and currently working on importing .obj files.

What is the best way to display a file explorer where the user can choose an .obj file and close the dialog. ( and store the file name/location in a string for me to use) ?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Right now, I have a File->import option, but the option doesn't do anything as I don't know how to open the file explorer.

Also, I have a obj file parser waiting for the file location to be passed to it. I have tested it with hard coded file locations as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use good old GetOpenFileName function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. For Vista and later you can use Common Item Dialog: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx